# How to solve this C++ multiple inheritance similar issue

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, multiple-inheritance

I'm wondering what is the recommended way to avoid the issue below.

I have a class rigidBody3D that has a pointer to another rigidBody structure, and a class box3D that inherits rigidBody3D.

```
class rigidBody3D {
public:
    void setPosition(float x, float y, float z);
    rigidBody* rb;
};

class box3D : public rigidBody3D {
public:
    box3D(float w float h, float l);
    ..other box functions..
};
```

I then have 2D classes that use these 3D classes.

```
class rigidBody2D {
public:
    rigidBody2D();
    void setPosition(float x, float y);
    rigidBody3D body;
};

class box2D : public rigidBody2D {
public:
    box2D(float w, float h);
    box3D box;
};
```

For example rigidBody2D's setPosition calls the 3D setPosition of its rigidBody3D.

```
void rigidBody2D::setPosition(float x, float y)
{
    body.setPosition(x,y,0);
}
```

THE ISSUE:

As is, creating a box2D object creates two rigidBody pointers. One because box2D inherits rigidBody2D which has a rigidBody3D. The other because box2D has a box3D object that inherits rigidBody3D.

I only want one rigidBody pointer. I also want to be able to call the 2D setPosition for 2D classes like box2D, but also call their 3D specific functions, like box2D calling box3D.

SOLUTION:

I used virtual inheritance to solve the problem, and also inherited the 3D classes instead of having objects of them.

```
class rigidBody3D {
public:
    void setPosition(float x, float y, float z);
    rigidBody* rb;
};

class box3D : public virtual rigidBody3D {
public:
    box3D(float w float h, float l);
    ..other box functions..
};

class rigidBody2D : private virtual rigidBody3D {
public:
    rigidBody2D();
    void setPosition(float x, float y);
};

class box2D : public rigidBody2D, private box3D  {
public:
    box2D(float w, float h);
};

void rigidBody2D::setPosition(float x, float y)
{
    rigidBody3D::setPosition(x,y,0);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by having a 2d body keep a 3d body? What real world situation are you trying to model?

Comment: why don't you inherit 2D bodies from 3D bodies, and set the `z` coordinate to 0? You should also probably think more about your design, and what should be in the base class.

Comment: The interface for the original rigidBody, that I have a pointer to, is all 3D. I want to keep my 3D layer as close to the pointer as I can. My 2D classes are to simplify my later tasks of adding 2D objects, which are 3D objects that are drawn in 2D and have their z components set to 0.

Comment: Redesigning is what I want to do. Do you have any suggestions, knowing that I want a 3D back-end and a simplified 2D interface?

Comment: This is one possible solution. Another one would be templatizing the hierarchy over number of dimension so that you have `object<2>`, `object<3>` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment:

> I want (...) 2D objects, which are 3D objects that are drawn in 2D and have their z
>   components set to 0

strongly suggest that a `rigidBody2D` ***is a*** `rigidBody3D`, and that a `box2D` ***is a*** `box3D`. Hence it would seem natural to prefer inheritance over compostion:

**Alternative 1:  simple inheritance**

Here we'll consider that the root of all these 2D and 3D objects is the rigidBody2D. 
One question remains:  is a box2D more a kind of box3D or more a rididBody2D ?

```
class rigidBody2D : public rigidBody3D {
public:
    rigidBody2D();
    void setPosition(float x, float y);
    // no body anymore:  it's inherited from rigidBody3D 
};
class box2D : public box3D {  // is it more like a box3d or more like a rigiBbody2D ? You decide ! 
public:
    box2D(float w, float h);
    // no box anymore:  it's inherited from box3D 
};
box2D::box2D (float w, float h) : box3D (w, h, 0) { /*...*/ }  // how to create a box2D as a special case of box3D

void rigidBody2D::setPosition(float x, float y)  // call the setpos of the parent.  
{
    rigidBody3D::setPosition(x, y, 0);  // call parent's setpos
}
```

All therse objects inherit from `rigidBody3D` and have then a pointer to a `rigidBody`.

A further question is in fact to know whether a `rigidBody3D` should not himself inherit from a `rigidBody`, or if there are strong arguments against (for ex: if the lifespan of the two are different).

**Alternative 2:  multiple inheritance**

Here it's about the design of box2D.  Is it more a box3D, having the same kind of member functions but than a box3D, but taking into account that third dimension is 0 ?  Or is it more a rigidBody2D,  because it should have and use all the member functions provided by this object ?

If you can easily decide, go back to alternative 1.

If you can't decide, because it's a little bit both, then you could consider multiple inheritance:

```
class box2D : public box3D, public rigidBody2D {   
public:
    box2D(float w, float h);
    // no box anymore:  it's inherited from box3D 
};
```

THen you would inherit member (function and data of both).  Hower multiple inheritance ain't easy.  You'd have here 2 rigidBody pointers:  those who are inherited from the box, and those who are inherited from the body.

This issue could be solved in your case by making inheritance of rigidBody3D virtual:

```
class rigidBody2D : public virtual rigidBody3D { ... };
class box3D : public virtual rigidBody3D { ... };
```

in this case, if an object inherits several time rigidBody3D,  only one of such subobject is created.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually used a combination of them both.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that 2d and 3d objects are related only by the fact that they are implemented in terms of a rigidbody*. The semantics of `setPosition` are different for the two concepts.

Another way to say this is that a 2d body is not a *kind-of* 3d body, it's a different concept so it seems that there should be no inheritance relationship between them.

so I would start by thinking along these lines:

```
struct rigid_body_3d_concept {
  virtual ~rigid_body_3d_concept();
  void set_position(double x, double y, double z) {
    _impl->really_set_the_position(x, y, z);
  }
private:
  rigidbody* _impl;
};

struct rigid_body_2d_concept {
  virtual ~rigid_body_2d_concept();
  void set_position(double x, double y) {
    _impl->really_set_the_position(x, y, 0);
  }
private:
  rigidbody* _impl;
};

struct box3d 
: public rigid_body_3d_concept 
{
    box3d(double w, double h, double l);
};

struct box2d 
: public rigid_body_2d_concept 
{
    box2d(double w, double h);
};
```